# UINavigationController app crashes when clicking the "back" button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

hoping someone can help me.

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I am loading and pushing detail view controller, when you tap the "back" button in the detail view to go back to the root view, the app will crash. No error logs or anything.

I'm 95% sure it's got something to do with the "rides" object being released too early, but can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

```
#import "RidesViewController.h"
#import "RideDetailViewController.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation RidesViewController
@synthesize rides;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.backgroundView   = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-view-background.png"]];

    rides                           = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString        *filePath       = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rides" ofType:@"JSON"];
    NSData          *jsonData       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    NSString        *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary    *results        = [responseString JSONValue];

    rides                           = [results objectForKey:@"rides"];

    [rides retain];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [rides count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) cell   = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.textLabel.text     = [[rides valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType      = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    RideDetailViewController *rideDetailViewController = [[RideDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RideDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSString        *aTitle         = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[rides valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString        *aImagePath     = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[rides valueForKey:@"imagePath"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString        *aDescription   = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[rides valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString        *aVideoPath     = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[rides valueForKey:@"videoPath"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [rideDetailViewController initWithTitle:aTitle imagePath:aImagePath description:aDescription videoPath:aVideoPath];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rideDetailViewController animated:YES];

    [rideDetailViewController   release];
    [aTitle                     release];
    [aImagePath                 release];
    [aDescription               release];
    [aVideoPath                 release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super  didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super  dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: When the app crashes in your developer build, immediately open the debugger and see which line in the code caused the crash. Then post that piece of code here and we can help you.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `NSString`'s in your header, then place them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Which NSStrings? The aTitle, aImagePath etc. Or the filePath string in viewDidLoad? I can't use the NSStrings in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath because I need the indexPath.row variable.

Comment: Actually, try them in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. The only other thing I had to do was retain each NSString, and I also had to add [self.tableView reloadData] in the viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

just **Cut** whole thing from `viewdidload` and **paste** this on `viewwillapper` method.

Comment: There is no crash log. It just crashes.

Comment: crashes how?  EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  SIGABRT?  If you're in "Debug" build, the debugger should help here.  What does it say in the Debugger console?

Comment: [rides retain];
remove this and paste other thing in viewwillapper?